# TLS 1.2 with old code on a new server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, ssl, windows-server-2012

I have an old (`.NET 2.0/3.5`) `SOAP` web service which we recently migrated from an old server to a new one that runs `IIS8` on `Windows Server 2012`.  I *assumed* that because one of the components involved (the code) didn't support `TLS 1.2`, then the service as a whole doesn't - even though both the server and the hosting process could work with it.

However, now I'd like to confirm that assumption. Do I have to upgrade the code to `.NET 4.5` for this service to be able to accept `TLS 1.2` requests?  Or are the requests handled correctly by the newer `IIS` regardless of what code it's running?

Comment: @ian - Why did you edit code tags into this question?

Comment: I didn't edit the tags. I only edited the format.. The tag edit was second revision and [was done by you](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32752679/revisions)

Comment: @Ian - I should have said, why did you edit code *blocks* into the question?  None of that is code.

Comment: the code blocks for programming terms/names/phrases tend to ease people for reading: `Windows Server 2012` because they are grouped together.